# Yii2 FTP File upload not working

Tags: php, ftp, yii2, ftp-client

I have used the yii2mod/yii2-ftp module for uploading FTP Upload. But its not uploading the temp file directly.

```
$uploadPath='/'.ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->district->district->district_name).'/'.'temp/'.$model->quick_string;
///district/temp/1508159604x16 this my upload folder
if ($FtpClient->mkdir($uploadPath)){
    $source_directory=$model->file->tempName;
    $target_directory=$uploadPath.'/'.$model->file->name;
    if($FtpClient->putAll($source_directory, $target_directory,FTP_BINARY)){
      echo "success";exit;
    }
}
```

output returned the error

> "dir(/tmp/phpizYNd7): failed to open dir: Not a directory"

Comment: You are trying to open a file instead of directory i guess.

Comment: no. i have upload a file using input type file.

Answer (score 0):

In yii2mod/yii2-ftp putAll Method Consider as a Directory.So the file could not possible to upload.Check the arguments is file or folder inside the function.

Vendor/yii2mod/yii2-ftp/ftpClient.php Line 606

```
public function putAll($source_directory, $target_directory, $mode = FTP_BINARY)
{

    if(is_dir($source_directory)){

        $d = dir($source_directory);
        // do this for each file in the directory

        while ($file = $d->read()) {

            // to prevent an infinite loop
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                // do the following if it is a directory
                if (is_dir($source_directory . '/' . $file)) {
                    if (!@$this->ftp->chdir($target_directory . '/' . $file)) {
                        // create directories that do not yet exist
                        $this->ftp->mkdir($target_directory . '/' . $file);
                    }
                    // recursive part
                    $this->putAll(
                        $source_directory . '/' . $file, $target_directory . '/' . $file,
                        $mode
                    );
                } else {
                    // put the files
                    $this->ftp->put(
                        $target_directory . '/' . $file, $source_directory . '/' . $file,
                        $mode
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $this->ftp->put(
            $target_directory, $source_directory,
            $mode
        );
    }

    return $this;
}
```